# in my snippets code below am trying to check the input radio button of liquid but can not be checked while bite can?

Tags: css

in my snippets code  below am trying to check the radio button from the next group but it is not
selective can not be checked here is the code:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 2px solid #f56;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f56;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="pizza" name="bites" value="pizza">
  <label for="male"><span></span>pizza</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="cake" name="bites" value="cake">
  <label for="female"><span></span>cake</label><br>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="soda" name="liquid" value="soda">
  <label for="male"><span></span>soda</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="water" name="liquid" value="water">
  <label for="water"><span></span>water</label><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` on the label doesn't match the radio input id, that's why your code is not working

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 2px solid #f56;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f56;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="pizza" name="bites" value="pizza">
  <label for="pizza"><span></span>pizza</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="cake" name="bites" value="cake">
  <label for="cake"><span></span>cake</label><br>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="soda" name="liquid" value="soda">
  <label for="soda"><span></span>soda</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="water" name="liquid" value="water">
  <label for="water"><span></span>water</label><br>
</div>
```